# HTTP/HTTPS C# MVC 5 Cookies being sent but not being recollected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, cookies

Ok basically when my website had no SSL certificate I was able to use my remember me cookies just fine

```
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Value = sessInfo.sid;
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Domain = "my-domain.com";
```

It worked just fine in this state. Once the  SSL Cert was added it still sends the cookie in site responses but the client does not send the cookie on request, same for HTTP. I then changed the code to what is below and still the issue persists.

```
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Value = sessInfo.sid;
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Domain = "my-domain.com";
 Response.Cookies["censid"].Secure = true;
```

Here is my code to try and retrieve the set cookie

```
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["censid"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            string sid = cookie.Value;
            UserIdFromSession userid = await UserHandler.validateSessionId(sid);
            if (userid.status == SessionResult.SessionSuccess)
            {
                Session["sid"] = sid;
                Session["username"] = UserHandler.getUsernameFromUserId(userid.userId);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            } 
        }
```

I still have HTTP enabled so people can access HTTPS and HTTP versions of my website, the cookies are still "set" but when I try to load the site again the cookies are not sent in the request.

Comment: Can you please provide shortened version of 2 HTTPS requests and first response that fail to send cookies on second request? (Obviously you don't expect cookies on HTTP, so not really sure why you highlight the fact your site can be accessed by HTTP as it is not relevant to the question)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added to the main post the code that tries to read the cookie.

Comment: Use Fiddler and capture actual request. Than clean them up and add just two https get to the question - one with response that set cookie and another that does does not sed cookies back. Or use dev tools of browser to do the same. Server side code that reads cookies does not help.